# SFDX : SOQL Query/Output

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am currently learning Salesforce DX/CLI to pull in data from my org.

I use the following syntax to extract Accounts data.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query  -u vpy.lightninglearn@gmail.com --query "SELECT ID, NAME FROM Account"
```

**Questions**

**a)** Is it possible to source the query from a file instead of in the command (*as many times the SOQL query may span across several lines*) ?

**b)** Is it possible to store the output into a file instead of just displaying the results in the Command Prompt (*as seen below*) ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use batch script to get SOQL from file or write to file.

**Fetch SOQL from File**

Read SOQL from file into a variable and use the variable in the sfdx command. Here's a simple `bat` file example (there are limitations to `set`).

```
SET /p soql=<my_soql.txt
echo %soql%

sfdx force:data:soql:query -q  "%soql%" -r=csv -u='user@gmail.com' > c:\temp\result1.csv
```

**Print output**

Pipe the output to print data to a file. For e.g. the below command will output CSV to the file.

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name FROM Contact LIMIT 10" -r=csv -u='user@gmail.com' > c:\temp\result.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mac/Unix, you can accomplish the same thing with `cat` and backticks:

SOQL=`cat my_soql.txt`; sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "$SOQL"

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell

```
# set up multiline query
$soql = @"
SELECT Id, NAME 
FROM Account
LIMIT 100
"@

# replace the carriage returns with spaces
$soql = $soql.Replace("`n"," ")

# run query, get results as powershell array 
# Note the ConvertFrom-CSV bit converts the comma separated strings
# into a list of powershell objects
$res = sfdx force:data:soql:query  -u $user --query $soql -r csv | ConvertFrom-CSV

# send results to console
$res

# you can process these results in powershell
# using Where-Object and Select-Object and so on
$res | Where-Object Name -like Fred*

# send results to CSV file
$res | Export-CSV "c:\temp\accounts.csv"
```

Above shows how to handle multi-line queries. You can also get the query from a file if you want, using the recently added --soqlqueryfile parameter. The file is allowed to have the query spread over multiple lines.

```
$res = sfdx force:data:soql:query -u $user --soqlqueryfile $queryFile -r csv | ConvertFrom-CSV
```